# Functional Tests getting a file from App_Data Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, functional-testing

I am writing functional tests and the method I am writing the tests for has to access a file in the App_Data Folder. I have tried

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/test.txt");
```

as well as

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "test.txt");
```

Both of them are not working. Is there a way to achieve this in functional test?

Any ideas in this regard is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Raja

Comment: In what way are they not working?  Do you get an error message of some kind?

Comment: It is throwing object reference not set to an instance of an object for the first one. That makes good sense since Httpcontext.Current will be null since I am running a functional test and not instantiating this service via HTTP. Second try (path.combine) does not work since it is just taking c:\App_Data\Test.txt which results in file not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at last (with the help of my solutions architect). We set up an app config for the functional test project and we set the file name as one of the appsettings. After that we specified the relative path to the actual file as a

```
[DeploymentItem(@"..\..\Project1\App_Data\Test.txt")]
```

attribute for the test class. We added a simple hack to use Absolute Path if it is in test (app config) and

```
Server.MapPath("Test.txt")
```

if it is not test. The logic to the solution is that since we put the file as a DeploymentItem it goes straight to the respective TestResults folder so if we use absolute path it is going to be able to reference it.

Hope this helps someone.